# Determine who picked up a Teams PSTN call from queue

Tags: microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I have been asked to report on Teams PSTN calls (no direct routing), in particular, who answered which call coming into a queue. I have connected to the graph API, but it appears the call record stays with the queue principal name and there is no indication of which Teams user answered.

Here is the call record:

```
{
  "id": "46be610d-9c0b-4ced-902b-XXXXXXXXXX",
  "callId": "341881824_117309704@99.99.99.99",
  "userId": "8d0192d9-2877-4351-8937-XXXXXXXXXX",
  "userPrincipalName": "VS_IncomingAA@tenant1.onmicrosoft.com",
  "userDisplayName": "VS_IncomingAA",
  "startDateTime": "2023-05-25T19:01:00.5470854Z",
  "endDateTime": "2023-05-25T19:03:30.5470854Z",
  "duration": 150,
  "charge": 0,
  "callType": "ucap_in",
  "currency": "CAD",
  "calleeNumber": "+18883441234",
  "usageCountryCode": "CA",
  "tenantCountryCode": "CA",
  "connectionCharge": 0,
  "callerNumber": "+14447779999",
  "destinationContext": null,
  "destinationName": null,
  "conferenceId": null,
  "licenseCapability": "MCOEV_VIRTUALUSER",
  "inventoryType": "Service",
  "operator": "Microsoft",
  "callDurationSource": "microsoft"
}
```

I cannot find a link to any other record. I hoped the callId would persist and get forwarded to another user.

Is there a way to determine who answered?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to determine who picked up a Teams PSTN call from queue.

If you wish you can suggest thi feature here: [Microsoft Teams Community](https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/forum/ad198462-1c1c-ec11-b6e7-0022481f8472)

Comment: Is there any way to get call queue information that would show the actual users? Maybe with Power Automate?